# Making Windows Wireless display more robust

Tags: windows, wireless-networking, display, multiple-monitors

I have [Gigabyte BL 4105 mini PC](https://www.amazon.in/gp/product/B07DMM7Z7N/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_title?ie=UTF8&psc=1) which has Intel Celeron J4105 processor. I was trying to use monitor to connected to as a second display for my laptop. I configured mini pc to allow projecting screen to it using [wireless display](https://www.wired.com/story/how-to-use-laptop-second-display-for-desktop-wireless/) ([official link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/screen-mirroring-and-projecting-to-your-pc-5af9f371-c704-1c7f-8f0d-fa607551d09c)). Once its done, the machine got listed in I was able to extend my laptop (connected to same WiFi) display to its monitor. But  this doesnt seem robust. Sometimes the extended screen pixelates. Other times it simply disconnects. Why this might be the case?

PS: My router is descent one (though very old), it can stream 1080p video quite well. Also my laptop screen and monitor resolution is FHD (1080p). My laptop runs Windows 10, while mini PC runs Windows 11.

Comment: Wifi frequencies are a shared media, a lot of different devices also use them. For video streaming short disturbances are  it a problem because the client usually buffers 10 to 60 seconds, but a wireless displays displays video data in real time, so any disturbance is directly visible.

Comment: I guess you are correct, as it is working smoothly now for some hours, when no one in my family is using it (they are asleep). But, is wireless display protocol so fragile?!  Is there absolutely no solution (configuration)!!! (Funny thing, it seem to struggle even when I play some media over Internet.)

Comment: Also remote desktop does not seem to have such issues. Is remote desktop not real time? Also is this tech not mature? Googling ["wireless display disconnects"](https://www.google.com/search?q=wireless+display+disconnects) gives many results related to Microsoft wireless display adapter and Miracast.

Comment: RDP requires a lot less bandwidth that a protocol like wireless display which works more like video streaming. Unless you are watching a video or somethin similar I would guess RDP requires may be a 10th of the bandwidth.

Comment: Yeah that might be the case. But I am wondering, if there is no way to fix this! This video data is not travelling Internet, but just local LAN. So only culprit can be router? And I have one option to try out better router?

Comment: Not really the router but the used Wifi. Use frequencies that are not used by other Wifis, (usually the 5GHz channels are not so crowded). 2. don't enable the option to use "broad channels" (broad channel = more frequencies = higher chance to get disturbed). 3. replace Wifi where possible by Ethernet (e.g. your Mini-PC to the router). Wifi devices don't communicate directly, instead they only communicate with the router which then forwards everything to the target device. So for a Wifi-to-Wifi connection the packet is sent two times though the Wifi.